# Binding CollectionViewSource to inner class

Tags: c#

I want to bind an inner ObservableCollection to CollectionViewSource for applying a filter to it. But unfortunately I failed on the first step. I was not able to bind my collection to the collectionViewSource as a new resources. I replaced the following code with works fine:

```
    <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Key="MyComboBoxFunctionColumn" Header="Function">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Mux.Setting.FunctionList}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedIndex="{Binding Mux.Setting.Id, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsEnabled="{Binding Mux.Applicable}" IsReadOnly="True" />                        
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

my Template is used in the following data grid:

```
   <DataGrid x:Name="pinTable" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding PortMux.Pins, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell" Grid.ColumnSpan="28">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Selection"  Binding="{Binding isSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="Auto"   Visibility="Hidden" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="MyComboBoxFunctionColumn"/>
```

in the code behind the cs file for the corrosponding xaml class I do the following

```
       public PortMux PortMux
    {
        get { return (PortMux)GetValue(PortMuxProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PortMuxProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PortMuxProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("PortMux", typeof(PortMux), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));...
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{...
       PortMux = new PortMux();
        ...

        PortMux = projectRef;
        ..
        base.DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
```

..

with the new collection class, but unfornately now my combobox items are empty, but I don't know why?

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="src" Source="{Binding Path=Mux.Setting.FunctionList}" >

    <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Key="MyComboBoxFunctionColumn" Header="Function">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource src}}"  DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedIndex="{Binding Mux.Setting.Id, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsEnabled="{Binding Mux.Applicable}" IsReadOnly="True" />

            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
enter code here
```

Any proposals that are fix my problem are welcome!!

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: The output pane of VS should tell you on what type of object it hasn't found such property.

Comment: Thanks Aybe for the hint, but there is no warning, error listed..

Comment: Try to use Snoop software to inspect the properties of your objects.

Comment: Hi Aybe, Snoop finds no binding error for this element:-(

Comment: Generally I do solve my binding issues with the 2 hints I've told you so not sure what's happening on your side. You should post a complete code sample because the one you've provided is incomplete, we can't help you out only from what you've posted.

Comment: Hi Aybe, I added some more information and maybe it helps to to find my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Aybe, I add some more information. Any help is welcome. Thanks!!